# expected "fi" is unexpected?

Tags: shell-script, files

I'm trying to check if a file size is less than 9999bytes, but I have no idea why it breaks right here..

```
if compgen -G "$jdir0/"*.srt 
then

for f in "$jdir0"/*.srt
do
    jsubtitle="$(basename $f)"
    filesize=$(du -b "$jdir0/$jsubtitle" | cut -f1)
        if [ "$filesize" -lt 9999 ] then
           echo "less"
        fi   #line 443
        if [ $filesize -gt 10000 ] then......etc,etc...



    **line 443: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'**
```

I've checked The variable $filesize, and it contains only numbers, no spaces, I've also tried without " " around the variable $filesize (and 9999) in the if statement.
I've also tested double [[, but no..

This is statement is inside another if statement inside a "for f in.." loop, but that shouldn't affect this?

Comment: Missing semicolon before `then`. [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is good at spotting common mistakes like this.

Comment: geee.. I literally have 100 if statement in the code, and never thought about it, and still I'm using both ; as a delimiter and have some places with then on the next line, and here I missed it for 5 hours.. sometimes you really can... ahhhhh.. thx for the help everybody

Answer (score 5):

I think your problem is that you have `then` on the same line as the conditional. It either needs to be on the next line, or have a semicolon before it.

Solution:
`if [ "$filesize" -lt 9999 ]; then`

Answer (score 2):

The `then` in your if needs to either go onto its own line or be preceeded by a `;`:

```
    if [ "$filesize" -lt 9999 ]; then
       echo "less"
    fi
```

Answer (score 1):

In:

```
if [ "$filesize" -lt 9999 ] then
           echo "less"
fi
```

That `then` is passed as an extra argument to the `[` command, not as the `then` keyword that would end the list of *condition commands* in the:

```
if
   condition-commands
then
   then-commands
〚elif
   more-condition-commands
then
   more-then-commands〛
〚else
   else-commands〛
fi
```

statement.

It becomes more obvious if you replace the `[` command with another simple command with a less unusual name such as `echo`:

```
if echo whatever then
  echo "less"
fi
```

Don't be fooled by stackexchange's syntax highlighting that identifies `then` as a keyword there even if the shell doesn't consider it as such here in an argument to a simple command like `echo` or `[`. You'll notice it does the same in:

```bsh
echo then
[ then = alors ]
```

The `fi` is unexpected because we need a `then` first. That `then` needs to be delimited somehow. So:

```
if [ "$filesize" -lt 9999 ]; then
   echo "less"
fi
```

Or:

```
if [ "$filesize" -lt 9999 ]
then echo "less"
fi
```

Technically,

```
if [ "$filesize" -lt 9999 ] & then
   echo "less"
fi
```

```
if ([ "$filesize" -lt 9999 ]) then
   echo "less"
fi
```

would also work in `bash` from a syntax point of view but that would not be  equivalent. The first one would run the `[` command in background (and we would just test that it has been successfully started in background), while the second would run it in a subshell.