# Nested if else statement in shell

Tags: shell-script

I could not understand whats going wrong with below if else statements.

```
if [ "$technology" == "AN_EUD" ] then
        if [ "$temporal_unit" == "15min" ] && [ "$regional_unit" == "node" ]
        then
                parm="DEVICEID"
        elif [ "$temporal_unit" == "15min" ] && [ "$regional_unit" == "trunk" ]
        then
                parm="DEVICEID"
        else echo "Unkown parameter"
        fi
else [ "$technology" == "IP" ] then
        if [ "$temporal_unit" == "15min" ] && [ "$regional_unit" == "item" ]
        then
                parm="ME_NAME"
        elif [ "$temporal_unit" == "min" ] && [ "$regional_unit" == "item" ]
        then
                parm="DEST"
        else echo "Unknown parameter"
        fi
fi
```

keeping getting below error

```
my.sh: line 67: syntax error near unexpected token `else'
my.sh: line 67: ` else [ "$technology" == "IP" ] then'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [expected "fi" is unexpected?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/606308/expected-fi-is-unexpected)

Comment: Paste the code into https://shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[@ilkkachu has already detailed the problems with your code](/a/635767), I'll just point out that you can make that a bit more concise with a `case` statement. Here, the three variables are just concatenated together, and the string matched against the known cases:

```
case "$technology:$temporal_unit:$regional_unit" in
  (AN_EUD:15min:node | AN_EUD:15min:trunk)
    parm=DEVICEID;;
  (IP:15min:item)
    parm=ME_NAME;;
  (IP:min:item)
    parm=DEST;;
  (*)
    echo >&2 Unknown parameter;;
esac
```

Since the patterns are fixed, any colons in the variables can't get mixed with the colons used as separators.

Note that one difference with your `if`/`fi` based statement is that an error will also be output if `$technology` is anything but `IP` or `AN_EUD`. You may need to adapt the code if that's not what you want.

Answer (score 5):

```
if [ "$technology" == "AN_EUD" ] then
                                ^
```

You're missing a semicolon there. The way it's written, `then` is just a regular argument to the `[` command, not a shell keyword. (The same way it's not a keyword in the command `echo if then else fi`.)

Bash complains about the later `else` being an unexpected token, because it's still looking for the `then`, and since the `else` is at the start of a command, it *is* recognized as a keyword. But it doesn't fit the syntax.

[Shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) also notices that, it says "Use semicolon or linefeed before 'then' (or quote to make it literal)."

After you fix that, there's this:

```
else [ "$technology" == "IP" ] then
```

That should probably be `elif` and not `else`. Without the semicolon before the `then`, this is actually fine as far as the shell syntax is concerned, the `[ "$technology" == "IP" ] then`  command is just part of the else-block. The test won't work because `[` expects to see `]` as the last argument, but the rest of the block is executed. If you add the semicolon, but leave the `else` as is, you should get an error for "unexpected keyword `then`".

The other issue in your tests is that while `==` works in Bash and ksh, it's not standard. The standard comparison operator in `[ .. ]` is `=`.

<sub>(Note, I didn't look at what you're actually doing, just the syntax and the error.)</sub>